# IE6 - jQuery UI Dialog - elements showing through overlay

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-6, jquery-ui-dialog

The demo at http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ states the following:

> The basic dialog window is an overlay
>   positioned within the viewport and is
>   protected from page content (like
>   select elements) shining through with
>   an iframe. It has a title bar and a
>   content area, and can be moved,
>   resized and closed with the 'x' icon
>   by default.

Can someone explain to me how their demo hides the `select` in IE6, as stated, but in my simple [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/r5N4X/), the `select` shines through?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="dialog">Hello</div>

<select>
  <option>Red</option>
  <option>Green</option>
  <option>Blue</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#dialog").dialog();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I figured it out. Apparently, looking at the source of the demo, they include [bgiframe](https://github.com/brandonaaron/bgiframe/blob/master/jquery.bgiframe.js) and, if that plugin is present, jQuery UI uses it with it's dialogs.

So for anyone wondering the same thing, simply include [bgiframe](https://github.com/brandonaaron/bgiframe/blob/master/jquery.bgiframe.js) in your project and you will be good to go.

---

On a side note, you would think that somewhere in their demo, they would mention that they were using the [bgiframe](https://github.com/brandonaaron/bgiframe/blob/master/jquery.bgiframe.js).